# Raster does not match the target extent and shape of another raster ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, netcdf, datum, climate

I have future climate data in .nc format. I transferred them into multiband rasters so I can separate them using another tool and make some calculations. I faced one issue in one variable where it had different extent and coordinates. It originally looked like this:

[image]

I rotated/adjusted the longitude to be -180 t0 180 and it became of same extent as other variables. However the shapes or land and sea position do not match with the other variables as it appear to be smaller and tilted a little.

[image]
[image]

I tried several things I knew but failed to solve it (define projection to wgs84, projected to it again, resampled). I'm not sure if I made a mistake somewhere and I never faced such issue before.

Comment: Is it specific to this .nc file? Did you check with any other available files?

Comment: no, I have several other variables like this all were marine variables. originally the nc to raster wouldn't work with lon, lat due to "error 000276: One or both dimensions have variable spacing in their coordinate values" so I tried using i, j instead and it gave me that upper map. I think the distortion is related to them, and to be honest I don't know what i,j truly represent, I was trying many things and this worked out.

Comment: The projections look off -- the coastlines in your first pic look more cylindrical equal area while the data looks more mercator.  NetCDF can allow the lon and lat to have variable spacing.  I'd look at the actual latitude coordinate variable in the netCDF file with something like `ncdump -v lat data.nc`

Answer (score 0):

**As a workaround:**

Create a feature layer first using the [Make NetCDF Feature Layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/tool-reference/multidimension/make-netcdf-feature-layer.htm) Geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS Pro, and then rasterize the created output. Specify latitude and longitude as Row Dimensions as well. Without row dimensions, the tool creates one point only using the 1st value of latitude and the 1st value of longitude.

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but then when tried to rasterize the output (through interpolation and feature to raster) it made a raster of the first band only. I thought in separating the bands of the feature output and rasterize each separately but I didn't find a proper tool to separate them.